# How can I get multiple alphabetic aggregates base on values in a single field and each buckets' count

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a single field: name.keyword.
I'd like an aggregation (or set of them to be laid out in a hierarchical breakdown) result to look like this:

```
all_names - a count of all distinct values for the name.keyword field
     names_a_through_e - a count of all distinct values that are limited to those values that start with "A" through those that start with "E"
          names_a - a count of all distinct values that are limited to those that start with "A"
               names - a list of each of these names and their count
          names_b - a count of all distinct values that are limited to those that start with "B"
               names - a list of each of these names and their count
          ...
     names_f_through_j - a count of all distinct values that are limited to those values that start with "F" through those that start with "J"
          names_f - a count of all distinct values that are limited to those that start with "F"
               names - a list of each of these names and their count
          names_g - a count of all distinct values that are limited to those that start with "G"
               names - a list of each of these names and their count
          ...
     ...
```

I can certainly cover the most inner lists like this:

```
    "a_names": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "name.keyword",
            "include": "A.*",
            "size": 100,
            "order": {"_term": "asc"}
        }
    }
```

But that does not give me a count at that level - a sum of all docs with A* in the name.keyword field.

Or is there a way to do this structured bucketing on a single field that will nicely organize the layout like I've described?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sum_bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html) to count total documents in a bucket.

Query

```
 {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "a_names": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.keyword",
        "include": "A.*",
        "size": 100,
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        }
      }
    },
    "totalcount": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "a_names._count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "a_names" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Abc",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "Count" : {
            "value" : 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Acf",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "Count" : {
            "value" : 1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "totalcount" : {
      "value" : 2.0
    }
  }
```